# htmlspecialchars is this redundant

Tags: php, pdo

do I need to use htmlspecialchars in both places of my code? 
I'm under the impression that the first instance will strip html from the entry boxes like the form boxes if they put html it will be stripped now the second part the form action where I also use htmlspecialchars i am under the impression this will strip the html from the post submission like if the tried to mod the query with injection i'm not sure if I have this right and i have a suspicion that i am doing more than I need or doing it wrong I don't know.

```
        <?php    
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $cost = $_POST['cost'];
    $source = $_POST['source'];      
    if($description !=''&& $cost !=''&& $source !='')
{
header("Location: ./");
}
    try {
    $dbh = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tao", "tao", "tao");
        }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
    exit;
}

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO benz (description,cost,source) VALUES (:description,:cost,:source)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cost', $cost, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':source', $source, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
 }
 $stmt = null;
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/five.css" />

<form class="basic-grey" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<p>Desc:<br />
<textarea cols="80" rows="2" name="description" id="description"></textarea></p>
<p>Cost:<br/><textarea cols="80" rows="2" name="cost" id="cost"></textarea></p>
<p>Srce:<br />
<textarea cols="80" rows="2" name="source" id="source"></textarea></p>




<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

I have have updated my code to reflect suggestions and it seems I need to focus on the displaying of the information from the db I'm not sure how to escape html when I pull the data from the database here is my code

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tao", "tao", "kt3");
        }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
    exit;
} 
$qry = 'SELECT * From benz';
$stmt = $dbh->query($qry);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
class nav {
  public static function GenerateMenu($items) {

    $html = "<div><ul id='menu'>\n";

    foreach($items as $item) {
      $html .= "<li class='meu'> {$item['class']} {$item['url']} {$item['text']}</li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul></div>\n";
    return $html;
  }
};

$menu = [];
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $menu[] = [ 
        'class' => $row['description'],
        'url' => $row['cost'],
        'text' => $row['source'],        
    ];
}; // end navigation
class total {
    public static function t() {
        try {
    $dbh = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tao", "tao", "tao3");
        }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
    exit;
} 
        $qry = 'SELECT SUM(cost) FROM benz';
        $stmt = $dbh->query($qry);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $htm = "<ul id='menu'>\n";
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $htm .= "<li class='meu'>Total {$row['SUM(cost)']}</li>\n";
        $htm .="</ul>\n";
        return $htm;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: of course it is redundant.

Comment: imo, i wouldn't bother with the `strip_tags` or `htmlspecialcharacters` on the way in. It will just be stored in the database as it is. I don't care. On the way out I would apply `escaping`. I would do validation checks on the input as usual.

Comment: @RyanVincent can you elaborate on this how do i do what you are suggesting?

Comment: @YourCommonSense and your response was no help

Comment: You are using prepared queries. Therefore, no data ever gets to be interpreted by the database engine. It is just a string that gets stored in the database. If the user wants to store html tags then so what. However, when I display it from the database _it must be 'escaped'_. I must not send anything executable from display fields to a web-browser. So, `htmlspecialchars` will be applied to all display fields when outputting the data.

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you that makes sense and is helpful thank you!

Comment: To make it really clear about prepared queries - you are using prepared queries **with placeholders** :) All the SQL injection issues go away.

Comment: @RyanVincent That is what I was hoping to achieve. Somewhere along the line i came into info that confused me obviously as you can see my post. I'll direct my attention to the page the displays the information thank you so much the way you explain it pretty clear to thank mate

Comment: @RyanVincent is there a way I could show you my display page seems that is the one I need to focus on i'm not 100% on how to escape the html if there is any when I pull the info from the db to display it

Comment: First, I like PHP as a `template engine` however because you have full access to PHP it can tempt you into taking 'shortcuts' when, really, you should be just outputting data without much logic. Therefore I suggest you look at a `templating engine`. Hmm, which ones have I committed to? My requirement is that they must be 'standalone components'. They should run on php 5.3 or 5.4 (don't ask). So, 1) [Twig is a modern template engine for PHP](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) And, 2) [Plates is a native PHP template system that’s fast, easy to use and easy to extend](http://platesphp.com/)

Comment: `Twig` does automatic escaping. You have to explicitly ask it to send 'raw' or 'unescaped data'. i.e. it defaults to being safe. It is easy to install and works fine. So, IMO,  for newcomers it is the  way to go. I like `plates` or just PHP or Twig all are fun :)

Comment: @RyanVincent I will look at both of these thank you for all the help and pointing me in a good solid direction thank you.